# Which Android Studio AVD to emulate a particular phone

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've create a simple app that works well on my HTC One. On my friends Sony Xperia Z3 Compact with a 4.6" HD (1280x720 pixels) screen, however, the layout get pretty messy. I'd like to emulate his screen on my Android Studio AVD, but haven't really found a device configuration that I think will be close. How do you guys suggest I go about deciding which device is the closes one? Being a HD screen I'm thinking I maybe should go for an xxhdpi density screen, which excludes all but the Nexus 5, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach for determining the emulator screen size.

Kenneth

Comment: You can customise an AVD to use a custom resolution, DPI and screen size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've found options to set up the desired resolution, but not the density. Which settings would you recommend for emulating a 4.6" HD having 1280x720 resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the latest stable/beta version of Android Studio, you can create a new AVD, and in the bottom left corner of the dialog, there's a button to "Create Virtual Device".

This opens a new dialog, on which you can select "New hardware profile".

Modify the fields to set the screen size as 4.6" and the resolution as 720x1280 (assuming you want portrait phone):

[image]

Note the density is displayed as `xhdpi`. **The density is not something you set: it's a [calculated value](http://mobilengineering.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/android-screen-densities-and-sizes-how.html) based on the [physical screen size and resolution](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)**.